# Java8 variable in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

```
int sum = a;
int pow = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    sum += b*pow;
    System.out.print(sum+" ");
    pow *= 2;
}
```

In Java-8 on using `Stream` gives errors for **sum** and **pow** variable that the variable should be **final**.

Comment: You could use a `AtomicInteger` instead of regular `int` to circumvent that issue.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: It's a workaround as well as a trick with an array, however, wrong by principle. The [tag:java-stream] provides mechanisms to process such operations.

Comment: How does your `Stream` attempt look like?

Comment: Seeing `AtomicInteger` is going to make readers wonder how a simple pipeline is concurrent, *and* impose another unnecessary performance penalty beyond converting the loop to a stream. I strongly discourage this abuse of the type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the generated Stream using [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and process the numbers in the same way. Note that [`Math::pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) returns `Double` therefore the pipeline results in [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html).

```
IntStream.range(0, n).mapToDouble(i -> b * Math.pow(2, i)).reduce(Double::sum);
```

The only disadvantage is no consumer is available during the reducing, therefore you have to amend it a bit:

```
IntStream.range(0, n).mapToDouble(i -> b * Math.pow(2, i)).reduce((left, right) -> {
    double s = left + right;
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
});
```

To answer this:

> In java8 on using stream give the errors for sum and pow variable that the variable should be final.

One of the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) conditions is that the variables used within lambda expressions must be either **final** or **effectively-final**, therefore the mutable operations you used in the for-loop are not allowed and have to be replaced with mapping feature of Streams. This issue is nicely explained at [http://ilkinulas.github.io](http://ilkinulas.github.io/programming/java/2016/03/27/effectively-final-java.html).

---

Remember, you cannot use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) the same way you use for-loops.